# Drawing without replacement, order matters - probability function

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not a mathematician, so the description of my problem might seem a little verbose:

In a multiple-choice test there is a set of three questions and a set of five possible answers. To each of the three questions one of the five answers is the correct one. No answer can be assigned twice. So three of the $5$ answers will be assigned to one of the three questions and two answers will be left.
I would now like to calculate the average score that would result from random answers if each correct answer yields one point.

If I'm not mistaken, in this case I have $n!(/n-r)!=60$ possible answer combinations, but I don't know what formula I use to calculate the probability of randomly hitting a combination with $0, 1, 2$ or $3$ correct answers. As far as I can see, this is a draw without replacement where the order matters, so I can neither treat it like a dice problem (e.g. "How likely are exactly three sixes in ten throws?" - binomial distribution) nor like a control sample ("How likely is it that exactly $5$ of these $100$ screws are defective?" - hypergeometric distribution), because then either the non-replacement or the order is not taken into account.

I wrote down all $60$ possible permutations and added up how many points each of them would yield. If I counted correctly, there ...

-... is one possible permutation that yields all three points,

-... are $6$ permutations that yield 2 points,

-... are $21$ permutations that yield 1 point,

-... are $32$ permutations that yield 0 points.

The table is in German, but I think it's not hard to guess what means what:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6gZB.jpg

Can someone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141329/discussion-on-question-by-philemur-drawing-without-replacement-order-matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments.  The OP has, correctly, done the full enumeration of cases and from that we can deduce that the expectation is $E=.6$

Of course, that method is badly error prone and, in any case, would not be practical in situations wherein the numbers were much larger.

Linearity gives us a much more efficient way to proceed.  Indeed, let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^3$ denote the scores attached to your three guesses in order.  Then of course $E[X_i]=\frac 15$ as any guess has a $\frac 15$ chance of getting a point (and a $\frac 45$ chance of getting $0$).  Then linearity tells us that $$E=E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=\sum_{i=1}^3 E[X_i]=\frac 35=.6$$
as confirmed by the full enumerator.

To stress: There is no claim that the $X_i$ are independent (indeed, they are not) but that is irrelevant, expectation is still linear.

Answer (score 1):

> I would now like to calculate the average score that would result from random answers if each correct answer yields one point.

You have $5 \times 4 \times 3 = 60$ possible responses to the test as a whole.

Let us assume your counting is right and there is $1$ combination giving three points, $6$ combinations yielding $2$ points, $21$ giving $1$ point and $32$ giving $0$ points.

Let $X$ be the variable denoting the points obtained from randomly answering the questions in the test. Then

$$\begin{cases}P(X=0) = \frac{32}{60}  \\ P(X=1) = 
\frac{21}{60} \\ P(X=2) =\frac{6}{60} \\ 
P(X=3) = \frac{1}{60}\end{cases}$$

which is equivalent to the discrete probability function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{32}{60}  & x = 0\\ 
\frac{21}{60} & x = 1\\ \frac{6}{60} & x = 2\\ 
\frac{1}{60} & x =3\end{cases}$$

Then, by definition of expected value, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = 0\times\frac{32}{60} + \frac{21}{60} + 2 \frac{6}{60} + 3 \times \frac{1}{60} = 0.6$$

So the *expected value* of $X$ is $0.6$.

Comment: Wait, your result is very different from the one I obtained by counting., How's that possible?

Comment: Fixed it, I was overcounting. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you, well, this is my result as well. My mistake is/was obviously that I thought this had anything to do with a drawing without replacement / random experiment. But it's obviously way easier.

Comment: It involves drawing without replacement, since that's a correct interpretation of the selection of answers from the set of all five possible answers. The problem differs in that it doesn't ask about the probabilities of the process of selecting the answers, but about the expected value of a different variable (the score in the test) that is associated to those probabilities.

Comment: This is exactly what I find hard to understand. Because as soon as the examinees answer one question, there are only two questions and 4 answers left. This is why I thought I had to take different "answering paths" (=permutations) into account.