# linearity of expectation, test scores and variance

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

I got a very good answer to my [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598601/drawing-without-replacement-order-matters-probability-function) on the subject and traced the proof of linearity of expectation through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1fSFvhPf7Q).

But I now have a total of three follow-up questions on the topic; sorry for that, but I have hardly done any maths for over a decade.

1. If I have an MC test with 45 questions, then the expected value X of the test score is calculated as the sum of the expected values $E(Y_i)$ of all individual items for purely random answer patterns:

$$E(X)=\sum_{i}E[Y_i]$$

Since there is one correct answer for each item and this yields exactly one point, the individual expected values of the item scores correspond to the reciprocal value of the amount of answer alternatives $a_i$:

$$E(Y_i) = \frac1a_i$$

Correct? I also hope that I have used the indices correctly ...

2. In one task, the situation is more complicated at first glance. There is a pool of 5 questions and 9 answers. For each of the 5 questions, exactly one of the 9 correct answers must be assigned, and the answers must not be repeated. In addition, there is a twist: one of the 9 answers *must* be used. What are the expected values in each case?
   My idea: For the answer that must be used, the expected value is $$E(Y)_m= \frac 15$$ For the other four tasks it is $$E(Y)_i=\frac 19$$ But I am anything but sure.

*Edit: Maybe one could divide this into two separate tasks: one where the answer thas *has to be used* gets randomly assigned to one of the items (chance 1/5) and then another one where one of the eight remaining answers gets randomly assigned to one of the remining 4 items, without any answer being used twice (chance 4 * 1/8)?*

3. How exactly do I calculate the variance of these expected values, especially for the total score? On the one hand, it should be possible to calculate the probabilities of all scores, because these result from the possible permutations. But according to which formula? On the other hand, it can be assumed that the answers are dependent, since the test is supposed to measure one and the same ability. This dependence is empirical.
   Maybe 'd better make a separate thread for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1 (Expected value for basic multiple choice problems)

Yes, that's correct.

### Question 2 (Expected value for match-the-answers problems)

Again you can take advantage of linearity of expectation. For the question whose correct answer is the "required selection", I agree there's 1/5 chance of guessing correctly. For one of the other questions,

How many total ways are there for the random answerer to respond to this group of questions? Well, first they must choose which answers will be used; there are $\binom{8}{4}$ options due to the 1 that's pre-locked. (See [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) if you aren't used to that notation.) Next, they must choose which answer gets assigned to which problem; there are $5!$ options. Overall there are $\binom{8}{4} 5!$ options.

How many ways are there for the random answerer to get a certain question right? Well, if we choose the question that's supposed to match with the "required answer", then there are $\binom{8}{4} 4!$ options because we can choose any 4 other answers to use and then assign them to the other questions however we want. That means P[correct] = $\frac{\binom{8}{4} 4!}{\binom{8}{4}5!} = \frac 1 5$ which matches your idea.

Now think about ways to get one of the other questions right. There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to select which answers to use (since we must include both the "required answer" and the correct answer to our chosen question) and then there are $4!$ ways to assign the answers (since we need to get our chosen question right, and then we could assign the other answers however we want). Thus there are $\binom{7}{3} 4!$ ways to get this question right, for a probability of $\frac{\binom{7}{3} 4!}{\binom{8}{4}5!} = \frac{1}{10}$.

Using linearity of expectation, the total expected score from this section is $\frac 1 5 + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {10} = \frac{3}{5}$.

### Question 3 (Variance; assuming problems are independent)

When working with *independent* random variables, the variance of the sum [equals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables) the sum of the variances. (This is different from dealing with expected values where linearity of expectation says that E[sum] = sum[expected values] even for dependent variables.) If the answers to different problems are independent then we can just add up the variances from each problem that's of "question 1" type. The variance per problem is $(\frac 1 4)(1-\frac 1 4) = \frac 3 {16}$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution#Variance)), so if you have $N$ such problems then the variance of the sum would be $\frac{3N}{16}$.

The variance for the problem cluster from question 2 is more difficult, but there's a trick that helps. Define random variables $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_5$ so that $X_j = 1$ if the answerer gets problem $j$ correct and $X_j = 0$ otherwise. Let $S = \sum_j X_j$ be the total score from this section. Assume for convenience that $X_1$ is the question whose correct answer is the "required answer"; this choice won't affect our result because the answerer assigns things at random anyway.

Now we have
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(S) &= E[S^2] - E[S]^2 \\
&= E\left[ \left(\sum_{j=1}^5 X_j \right)^2 \right] - \left(\frac 3 5 \right)^2 \\
&= E\left[ \sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 X_j X_k \right] - \frac 9 {25} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 E\left[  X_j X_k \right] - \frac 9 {25} \\
\end{align}$$
where the last step used linearity of expectation to split up the sum. Note $E[X_j X_k] = P[\text{get questions $j$ and $k$ both right}]$. Let $P_{jk}$ denote this quantity and let $P_j = P[\text{get question $j$ right}]$. Now we can break into cases depending on $j$ and $k$ and solve similarly to how we answered question 2 above.

1. $j=k=1$. In this case we have $P_{jk} = P_1 = \frac 1 5$ as computed in the Question 2 section above.
2. $j=k>1$. We have $P_{jk} = P_j = \frac 1 {10}$ as computed above.
3. $j=1<k$. If we need to get questions $j,k$ both right then there are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to pick which answers to use, and then $3!$ ways to assign those answers. So $P_{jk} = \frac{\binom{7}{3} 3!}{\binom{8}{4} 5!} = \frac 1 {40}$.
4. $1 < j$, $j \not = k$. To get questions $j,k$ both right, there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to pick which answers to use, and then $3!$ ways to assign those answers. So $P_{jk} = \frac{\binom{6}{2} 3!}{\binom{8}{4} 5!} = \frac{3}{280}$.

Now let's combine these to compute $\sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 E\left[  X_j X_k \right]$. In that sum, case (1) will occur 1 time, when $(j,k) = (1,1)$. Case 2 appears 4 times, with $(2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)$. Case 3 appears 8 times if we also include cases with $1=k<j$ which will have the same probability. Case 4 appears $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ times. So overall we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 E\left[  X_j X_k \right] = 1 \left(\frac 1 5 \right) + 4 \left( \frac{1}{10} \right) + 8 \left( \frac{1}{40} \right) + 12 \left( \frac{3}{280} \right) = \frac{13}{14}$$
and finally
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(S) &= \sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 E\left[  X_j X_k \right] - \frac 9 {25} \\
&= \frac{13}{14} - \frac{9}{25} = \color{blue}{\frac{199}{350} \approx 0.5686}.
\end{align}$$

### Bonus strategy: Just code it.

Depending on your background, it's possible you might want an approximate answer without going through all the formulas above. You could do that very quickly by just coding a quick script that chooses random answers a bunch of times and tracks the results. Here is an implementation in Python:

```
import itertools
import random
import numpy as np

def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(range(n), r))
    return list(pool[i] for i in indices)

NUM_TRIALS = 10**6

sum_score = 0
sum_score_sq = 0
for _ in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    chosen = [0] + random_combination(range(1, 9), 4)  # which answers will we use?
    np.random.shuffle(chosen)  # assign the answers to problems randomly.
    score = sum(1 for k in range(5) if chosen[k] == k)
    sum_score += score
    sum_score_sq += score*score

E = sum_score * 1. / NUM_TRIALS
var = sum_score_sq * 1. / NUM_TRIALS - E**2

print(E)
print(var)
```

You can tune `NUM_TRIALS` if you want higher or lower accuracy. 1 million trials took a second or two on my laptop and I got $E(S) \approx 0.599841$ and $\text{Var} \approx 0.5681$, which are pretty decent approximations to the exact answers computed above. If you want a bit more accuracy you could always dial up `NUM_TRIALS`, but if you want a lot of correct decimal places it'll start taking a very long time. Still, this can often be the right method when you just want to get a rough approximation quickly.

### Question 3 (Variance; not assuming problems are independent)

The above can be a fun calculation, but of course I agree with your observation that a student who performs well on one question is often more likely to do well on the other questions. Trying to model that relationship will make this a more complicated problem: you can't even start thinking about computing expected value or variance until you lock in what assumptions you'll use about how the variables depend on each other.

Basically, this is a very reasonable followup question but it makes the discussion much more complicated so I agree with your guess that it will be more productively discussed in a separate followup thread. Seems like you want that followup thread to cover both 1) what would be a reasonable set of assumptions to make about the relationships between a student's success on different problems? and 2) how do you compute score mean and variance in that new model?

### [EDIT] Followup #1: Why isn't it simpler?

In the comments, OP asked about why linearity of expectation doesn't make these calculations super simple+short like it did on their recent similar post. I'll explain more here. The "basic MC" problems really were very simple above, so I'll focus on the "match the answers" problems.

For notation, I'll use Q1, Q2, $\cdots$, Q5 to denote the five problems, and A1, A2, $\cdots$, A9 to denote the nine answers. We can safely assume A1 is the "must be included" answer and that the correct answer to Q1 is A1, correct answer to Q2 is A2, $\cdots$, correct answer to Q5 is A5. (These assumptions won't change the success probability because the student is guessing totally at random anyway.) I'll still use $X_j$ to denote the random answerer's score on question Qj.

During the computations above, I calculated several quantities like $E[X_j] = P[\text{get Qj right}]$ and $E[X_j X_k] = P[\text{get Qj AND Qk right}]$. If you can figure out what those probabilities are in some clever way, then I absolutely agree you don't need the permutations/combinations stuff. For example, with $E[X_1]$ you could save yourself a lot of trouble by just realizing: "A1 will always be assigned to one of the five questions, so there's a $\frac 1 5$ chance that it gets assigned to Q1, so $E[X_1] = \frac 1 5$." This is how you argued in the problem statement and I totally agree; in fact that's how I would have solved this case if I were doing the problem myself.

On the other hand, one of the hardest parts of probability is getting the hang of when it's safe to take an intuitive-sounding shortcut vs when your intuition may be leading you astray. For $E[X_2]$, you guessed that the probability should be $\frac 1 9$ because there are 9 possible answers, but actually the answers aren't all equally likely to get assigned to Q2. The issue is that A1 has a higher chance to end up assigned to Q2 because it's always among the 5 selected answers, which means A2 ends up with $< \frac 1 9$ chance of getting assigned to Q2.

It would still be possible to compute $E[X_2]$ by "clever tricks" methods, but they'd be a little more complicated, and honestly I wouldn't bother. It's not that hard to do the permutations/combinations way, and I find it much easier to avoid "intuition traps". If I were doing this problem myself, for this part I would realize that the intuition isn't 100% straightforward and just go write out the P&C formula instead of bothering with trying to be clever.

And that's not even getting into $E[X_j X_k]$. Trying to "understand intuitively" and write down the answer without using permutations/combinations sounds awful. Once you get into tougher tasks like this, I would always recommend just rolling up your sleeves and writing down some binomial coefficients and factorials.

(Of course, I realize that you're running into some issues setting up the P&C calculations too. I'll say - with a bit more practice, I think it's much easier to get consistent at setting those calculations up. It's still worth also practicing the "write the answer down based on intuitive reasoning" approach, but definitely need to fall back to careful computations when your intuition says you might be missing something.)

### [EDIT] Followup #2: Specific formula question

OP asked for more clarification about why there are $\binom 8 4 5!$ total ways for the random answerer to respond.

Your proposed formula of $\binom 9 4$ would tell me: "How many ways are there to choose 4 items out of 9 options, without replacement, with order not mattering?" Some parts of that match up with what we want, but other parts don't.

The actual situation is: "How many ways are there to start with 1 item already chosen, then choose 4 more out of 8 possibilities without replacement, where order of the 5 items DOES matter?". The differences from your formula are:

- You should choose 4 items from 8 options, not 4 from 9. The "forced selection" can't be picked again.
- You do care about order, so once you finish picking which 5 answers will be used, you need to multiply by $5!$. Multiplying by 5 would not be enough here; with the P&C approach, I'm calculating how many ways there are to fully assign answers to all 5 questions.

That's why the formula I ended up with was $\binom{8}{4} 5!$ instead. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Hello David, thank you so much for your extensive and very helpful reply! Now give me some time to digest it, especially the second part makes me think. It seems to be a totally different solution from the one we found for a similar problem in my previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598601/drawing-without-replacement-order-matters-probability-function

Comment: @Philemur I've edited in responses to your questions even though it seems like maybe you deleted them. They're good + totally valid questions! I especially like the one about why we aren't able to avoid the messy computations this time even though it was possible on that other similar-sounding question. That would have been good for me to cover better in the original answer.

Comment: Hi David, I actually deleted them because I thought they could be misleading for others. I now fully understand your answer to my second question and I must say that you couldn't have done a better job, actually. It is very clear, it just took me a while to understand and get all the concepts right. Now I need to take a break and get back to the variance problem. But thanks again, with this second part you brought clarity to some vague and clouded intuitions of mine and showed me the way. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entirely understand the splitting-up of the sum. I understand that you have to distinguish the "required answer" from the others, but I'm not really seeing where this sum of a sum of a product (if that's right?) is coming from. The distinction of cases seems clearer to me, but to fully understand why it's exactly 4 I need to get that part with the sum first. Sorry for the hassle, like I said before, it's been more than a decade that I had to understand some complicated mathematical problem thoroughly.

Comment: As for the 4 cases: Why only four? Don't we also have to include cases where 3, 4 or all 5 questions are answered right to compute the variance? I assume these cases are included somewhere where I'm not seeing them... when maths and me disagree it's usually me who is to blame. :) But wait... it's in E[S], right?

Comment: @Philemur The math right after "Now we have" shows that we can compute the variance as long as we can compute $P[X_j=1, X_k=1]$ for any $j,k$. So then the 4 cases just cover all the different types of pairs $j,k$. (For example, $j=2,k=3$ and $j=3,k=5$ don't need separate cases because those probabilities will be the same.)

Comment: Re splitting up the sum: Can you say a specific line that doesn't make sense? Or are you saying you understand each line but don't see why it's useful to split it up like that? If the latter, my explanation is that this "write $S$ as a sum of $X_j$ and then split up the sum" idea is a way to get the variance just by computing $P[X_j=1, X_k=1]$. Otherwise I'd be stuck trying to compute $P[S=k]$ for each $k$ which would get messier. It's quite an advanced trick IMO; I know it from solving contest problems, not from any math course. Still happy to answer followup questions about it though.

Comment: It seems quite advanced, yes. :) And I'm, pretty sure that all your lines make sense, I'm just struggling with seeing it. It's hard to say what exactly I'm still missing. I think it's basically how you got to this line: $$E\left[ \sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 X_j X_k \right] - \frac 9 {25}
$$

Comment: I think you need to split into j and k in order to distinguish between the one "pre-locked" and the eight "open" answers. And the product $X_j X_k$ somehow replaces the squaring. But I'm not seeing, for instance, how this adds up to 1/5 if j=k=1. But maybe I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: $S = \sum_{j=1}^5 X_j$, so $$S^2 = \left( \sum_{j=1}^5 X_j \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^5 X_k \right),$$ so $$E[S^2] = E\left[ \left(\sum_{j=1}^5 X_j \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^5 X_k \right) \right] = E\left[ \sum_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^5 X_j X_k \right].$$

Comment: Sometimes the missing piece is just a detail... I'm starting to understand now. But let me think about it a little longer and then also sleep over it, before I precipitately post something confused or confusing. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Btw, I think the first square might be in the wrong position in the second line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141375/discussion-between-david-clyde-and-philemur).